# Lazy Evaluation implementation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have a function `fromRange` which takes a filter function and an interval and returns a set with all elements in the interval that satisfy the filter function.

I implemented it using list comprehension:

```
fromRange   :: (Integer->Bool) -> (Integer,Integer)  -> [Integer]
fromRange f (x,y) = [i | i<-[x..y], f i]
```

but it takes very long time with big list so I found the lazy evaluation concept but I do not know how exactly to implement it, any help??

Comment: Would you also add the context in which you're using the function, so that it is slow?

Comment: `fromRange <anyF> (<anyX>, <anyY>)` should be basically free, as it just creates a thunk. How are you using it (and thus forcing evaluation)? Also note that a sweeter definition would be `fromRange f (x, y) = filter f [x..y]`, at which point you might as well forget about it and just use `filter <pred> [a..b]` everywhere.

Comment: @bereal for example fromRange odd (1,1000000000)

Comment: and how do you call this `fromRange odd (1,1000000000)`? At the GHCi's prompt? If so, this forces the whole list, in order to print it. But if you'd call `head $ fromRange odd (1,1000000000)`, you will immediately get the `1` back. That is what laziness means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lazy evaluation is not supposed to be faster for large datasets, it only postpones the evaluation until the very moment when the value is needed. For example, if you type in your `ghci`:

```
fromRange (< 50) (1, 1000000000)
```

you'll have to wait forever before it iterates through the whole list to filter it and print the result.

On the other hand:

```
take 10 $ fromRange (< 50) (1, 1000000000)
```

will complete instantly, because it does not have to calculate the rest of the list.

Note: `take 100` will hang as well, since it won't ever find enough entries.

Comment: so the lazy is to get what i need and do not evaluate the rest do i understand you correctly

Comment: @user1837422: exactly, you get only _what_ you need and not until _when_ you need it (in your case, for the console output).

Comment: but what if i need the last element only do i have to wait until it is finished

Comment: @user1837422 yes, lazy evaluation can't help that. If you want something from the end of an arbitrary list, you'll have to iterate until the end (think of a Fibonacci sequence).

Comment: @user1837422 or you'd have to change your algorithm: `last $ filter f [x..y] == head $ filter f [y..x]`. Be careful whether this is actually an improvement or not, like for the code example in this answer, were you'd have to go even deeper to rearrange and optimize it.